# How to dequeue message in Azure queue after TTL

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I'm using queue to control number of message.

I set each message 1 minute TTL.

After 1 minute, these message are invisible but the total of message in queue does not decrease.

So, can the Azure queue dequeue automatically after TTL of message is over?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, can the Azure queue dequeue automatically after TTL of message is
> over?

No, because the message will be permanently removed from the queue after TTL has expired for the message.

Comment: The problem is the message is not actually removed. If you use Storage Explorer of use Queue.ApproximateMessageCount, the number of message does not decrease after message is expired

Comment: Approximate message count is approximate only so it may not reflect the exact number all the time. Having said this, once the message expires it should be removed from the queue. Can you try with a single message in a queue? Create a new queue, put a message with say 1 minute TTL and try to peek the messages from the queue after 1 minute. You should not see any messages in that queue.

Comment: Thank you. I think so. The approximate count look like a metric number rather than actual message in queue. The queue messages are removed actually.